# VBA Excel Error 91, error while setting an object

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem with my VBA Excel code, I'm trying to merge selected cells and put the data that is behind it where the words were merging. (Deleting the cell didn't work.)

Here is an example (`|` is the separator for the cells):

> |Stack|Overflow|100|None|Something|

Run the code and it should look like this:

> |Stack Overflow|100|None|Something|

But I'm getting "Error 91 Object variable or With block not set," here is the code:

```
Dim Cells As Range
Dim CellsContents As String
Dim RangeCells As Range
Set RangeCells = Application.Selection

For Each Cells In RangeCells
    CellsContents = CellsContents & Cells.Value & " "
Next
RangeCells.Value = VBA.Left(CellsContents, VBA.Len(CellsContents) - 1)
Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + Selection.Count), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 20)).Copy Destination:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + Selection.Count - 1)
```

The error is happening on the last line of the code. I tried to put `Set` before it with an object variable but then I got an error on the destination. If you want some more information on this because I know it's a little confusing just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use "cells" this way. You need to reference a worksheet object before:
ie. activesheet.cells or worksheet("SheetName").cells

replace the last line with the below and it should work.

Hope this helps.

```
Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + Selection.count), ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 20)).Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + Selection.count - 1)
```

Comment: While not recommended, one certainly can use `Cells` without putting `ActiveSheet` in front of it, as the `Application` object has a property named `Cells`, and one can access properties of the `Application` object without saying `Application`. The OP's problem is a name collision where a local variable shadows the global `Cells` property.

Comment: looks like there were 2 ways to solve it this one and the other one where I changed the Dim Cells to Dim Cell because that was intervering with each other but thank for the tip with the activesheet.cells

Comment: Agreed. But I think in this case he needs to put ActiveSheet in front for this to work because there is a conflict with the user defined variable Cells which is getting picked up instead of the Application object property.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in the last line the variable Cells is no longer in scope.

Hence you get the error you describe "object variable not set".

Comment: The variable `Cells` is still in scope, but was assigned with `Nothing` after the `For` loop ended. Apparently the OP meant to use `Application.Cells` but ended up using the variable `Cells` because it is more local.

Comment: I changed the Dim Cells to Dim Cell because in the last line I did not use the variable Cells but the method Cells to indicate which row and columns it need to copy and paste in. That was intervering with each other. So thanks after I read your answer I realised it!

Comment: @GSerg Yep that is true but I realised it when I read his answer. So he sort of solved it?